# ¿Como puedo poner un if de rango dentro de un for?

Tags: java

[![[1]][1]

Necesito hacer un programa con do-while y switch que capture 6 calificaciones entre un rango de 6 a 10 y despues sacar el promedio, todo me va bien, Para capturar las 6 calificaciones utilizo un ciclo for y me funciona a la perfección, pero cuando quiero poner el rango de 6 a 10 con el if dentro del for, no me funciona, me corre el for contando sin contar el if, es decir, cuando ingreso un número fuera de rango por ejemplo 3 el for lo que hace es seguir contando como si nada pasara un ejemplo de lo que pasa al correr el programa es:

For

Ingrese su calificación: 1
2 //numero fuera de rango
Ingrese su calificación: 2
4 // numero fuera de rango
Ingrese su calificación: 3
y asi se va suseccivamente sin reiniciar el for cada que ingrese un numero fuera de rango, lo que yo quiero es que si se ingresa un numero fuera de rango se reinicie de nuevo el for y cuente desde cero otra vez

Este es mi codigo:

```
        int op;
    int i;
    double n = 0;
    double suma = 0;
    int ban = 0;
    do {
        op = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1.Capturar \n2.Mostrar \n3.Salir"));
        switch (op) {

            case 1:

                for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
                 
                        n = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su calificacion: " + i));
             
                        suma = suma + n;
                }  
                         suma = suma / 6;
                        ban = 1;


                break;

            case 2:
                if (ban == 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su promedio es de: " + suma);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha capturado datos");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saliendo del programa");
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de opcion");
                break;

        }

    } while (op != 3);

}
```

}

Comment: Debes poner tu codigo como texto no como una imagen

Comment: Perdón soy nuevo aquí, Gracias

Comment: Quieres poner un `if`, perfecto, ¿dónde exactamente quieres ponerlo? ¿qué problema tienes para hacerlo?

Comment: ya corregí mi publicación, espero me logren entender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo harías de la siguiente forma

```
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
                
    n = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su calificacion: " + i));
    if(6>n<10){
          suma = suma + n;
      }else{
          i = 0            
      }
       
}
```

En el bloque del `if` evaluas la entrada de `n`  en la cual está la condición de que el valor de `n` debe ser mayor que 6 y menor que 10  y el resto es el código que tienes

Comment: Ayudaría mucho si añades una explicación a tu código, con un código sin explicación nadie aprende nada, por más que sea obvio de entender que hace el código, hay usuarios que no entienden si no hay una explicación.

Comment: Gracias ya corregí mi publicación

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta, espero que sea lo que quieres, de lo contrario dejamelo saber

Comment: muchas gracias ya me funciono